<p>..</p> HTML tags appear with the field value when using post to chatter action
I have a flow where I am using post to chatter action , I created a resource (Text templte type) and inserted the fields with view as plain text. Still I am seeing value of the field with html tags in the chatter section. This is happening for only one field which is a rich text area field.
I want to see the value of this rich text field without these html tags.I have already used view as plain text but still this field value is coming with html tags.
Is there any other way to get rid of these html tags.
